# How do I retrieve node data for a referenced node in a template file?

Tags: nodes

I have two content types, Event and Gallery. Each Event has a node-reference field to a gallery. I am now trying to style the gallery node page from inside the template file. I need to have a way of creating a link which links back to its parent, the Event.

How can I find this information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it seems you need to know value of node which is referring the current node.
I am assuming machine name for the refernce field you have on event content type as "field_event_gallery"

In your custom module or template.php
// function to get backrefernce value.

```
function mymodulename_get_back_refernce_value($current_nid) {
  $nids = array();
  $results = db_select('field_data_field_event_gallery','n')
            ->fields('n',array('entity_id'))
            ->condition('field_event_gallery_nid',$current_nid)
            ->execute()
            ->fetchAll();
  if(is_array($results) && count($results) > 0) {
    foreach($results as $result) {
      $nids[] = $result->entity_id
    }
  }
  return $nids;
}
```

Now in your theme template.php use template_preprocess_node(),something like below

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  $node = $variables['node'];
  if ($node->type == 'gallery') {
    //get referring nids
    $referring_nids = mymodulename_get_back_refernce_value($variables['node']->nid);
   if(count($referring_nids) > 0) {
     foreach($referring_nids as $referring_nid) {
       $referring_node = node_load($referring_nid);
       $variables['parent_event_link'][$referring_nid] = l(t('View parent event: @event_title', array('@event_title' => $referring_node->title)), 'node/' . $referring_nid);
   }
  }
}
```

finally in your template loop through $variables['parent_event_link'] and print it.

**My codes are not tested, you have to debug to make them workign for you**

Comment: @user1015214 did you get check this code?

Comment: Sorry, I was having computer issues last week. Yes, the code works! Thanks! But you had a typo, it should say $results = db_select...

Comment: oh, also, I needed to change the 'n' in  fields('n',array('entity_id')) to 'eg', to match the line above

Comment: updated just an table alias :)

Answer (score 0):

The best way to prepare this for template is through `hook_preprocess_node()` implementation.

This code should be in your theme's `template.php` file:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  $node = $variables['node'];
  if ($node->type == 'gallery') {
    // You can add new attributes to the $variables variable and they will be
    // available automatically in the node template file as direct variables.
    $variables['parent_event_link'] = l(t('View parent event: @event_title', array('@event_title' => $variables['field_gallery_event'][0]['node']->title)), 'node/' . $variables['field_gallery_event'][0]['nid']);
  }
}
```

And in your `node.tpl.php` or `node--gallery.tpl.php` file you can use:

```
<?php print $parent_event_link; ?>
```

Comment: I guess he is asking for backreference.

Comment: This wont work, there is no field_gallery_event inside of the gallery node, thats my issue.

Comment: Install devel module and check the output of `dpm($variables)` in `hook_preprocess_node()`. Are you trying to do this on single node page or somewhere else?