# How do I use arguments with the Path Breadcrumb module?

Tags: breadcrumbs

I am using the Path Breadcrumbs module to create breadcrumbs. I don't fully understand how to use arguments and selection rules, and thus I'm not sure how to create the following breadcrumb:

On the gallery node page (/gallery/%node), I want to use *home > events >[event-name] > schedule* as breadcrumbs.

Every Event node contains a node reference to a gallery node. I am trying to add this event name to the breadcrumbs. I already have retrieved the event name from `$variables`, following  [How do I retrieve node data for a referenced node in a template file?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/88640/how-to-retrieve-referring-node-data-from-inside-a-template-file)

Answer (score 0):

As an last option you can implement theme_breadcrumb() in your theme template.php

Something like below sample code.

```
function themename_breadcrumb($variables) {
  if (arg(0) == "galery" && is_numeric(arg(1))) {

    // Get event title of the  event
    $event_nids = mymodulename_get_back_refernce_value(arg(1));

    // Note since a gallery can be referred by multiple event nodes so you have add logic which one you need to pick here, for now I am picking with array index as 0
    $event_node = node_load($events_nids[0]);

    $links[0] = l(t('Home'), '<front>');

   // inplace of 'events' add internal link path to events page.
    $links[1] = l(t('Events'),'events');
    $links[2] = l(t($event_node->title),'node/'.$event_node->nid);
    $links[3] = t('schedule');
    drupal_set_breadcrumb($links);
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried your code, with a few changes - if (arg(0) == "gallery") - and - $event_nids = get_back_reference_value($variables['node']->nid); but nothing happened. I changed the name to my theme name and flushed the cache, but I don't think the code is ever being picked up. I tried a drupal_set_message and it never displayed either.

Comment: do you have devel installed?

Comment: @user1015214 can you join this chat room http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11070/breadcrumb

Answer (score 0):

The *Path Breadcrumbs* module works with system paths. For nodes system path looks like node/%, you can read more in the module [FAQ](https://drupal.org/node/2061955) and [documentation](https://drupal.org/node/2061939).

The main problem with your example is that your **Gallery** content type doesn't have a reference field to **Event**, so other modules don't know if *this* Gallery node is referenced from *that* Event node.
There is a list of modules which may help with it on [How do I implement two-way node references?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/455/how-to-implement-two-way-node-references) (I didn't test them.)

Another way is to provide a computed entity property "Event" for Gallery content type with `hook_entity_property_info_alter()`. Doing so, your property will be available as a token in Path Breadcrumbs.